# How to delete files during installation with installshield 2010

Tags: file, installshield, delete-file

I'm including in my installation package some backup files from my database, so I can restore it and have a complete running database in one easy step, and it's all fine, but i'd like to delete the database backup files as a step in the installation process right after it's restored.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some InstallScript to do the job as a custom action.  There is a function [DeleteFile](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/installshield20helplib.htm) that does that.

Look at the link to the example at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I was looking for, but I have a follow-up question, after I include the script into the project and add the custom action to launch it I keep getting an error "Error compiling setup.rul. Setup.rul is required to be included in the project..." :S If I delete the custom action, that error disapears... Any idea?

Comment: Found this in their help stuff... hope it helps:  To resolve this error, it is necessary to insert a file entitled Setup.rul into the project. To accomplish this, follow these steps:

1. Select the InstallScript view.
2. Right-click on the Files folder and select New Script File to insert a new InstallScript file.
3. If not already present, rename one of the script files to Setup.rul by right-clicking the file and choosing Rename.
4. Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Booberry's answer, I suggest you make this a [deferred custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), because you will be making actual changes to the system. Once you do this, you won't be able to access your properties so you will have to pass the file path via [Custom Action Data](http://www.installshield.com/news/newsletter/0308-articles/CustomActionData.asp).

Besides this, I also suggest you consider the approach of using your database backup, if in the future your application is deployed to international markets you will find issues with the collation (which may vary depending on the country) and cause your customers (and yourself) a headache.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Deletefile function will not remove "Read-Only, Hidden and system files".You have to remove the Read-only attribute then use delete file function..

If you are running this as a custom action , then choose deferred execution in system context mode.